# Bootstrap modal not showing up, screen just has black overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm trying to get a modal to show on my bootstrap site, and when I click the button to trigger it the screen turns dark, but nothing shows up.

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I'm using as well, in addition to JQuery, popper.js, bootstrap js

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
```

I literally took this right off the bootstrap site and for some reason it's not working.

```js
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where is `#myInput` ?

Comment: your snippet is working for me . what is the problem ?

Comment: The example you provided works as expected so it could be due to where you are actually placing the `.modal` on your page as another element's z-index could be causing this for instance.

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet for the modal is perfectly fine, Check the parent div for both trigger and the modal and raise their z-index, It very likely that the Z-Index of the parent element is interfering with the modal pop up. You can try this`

```
.parentElementOfModal{
  z-index:10000;
}
```